# Google Play PreLaunch report

Tags: flutter, publish, google-play-console

I am new to google play publishing and flutter development. I created a very simple application to understand the process. When I published my app to the google play store, I got a prelaunch report which says **Errors found. Fix before releasing to production**.
I found one crash related error and all others were warnings.

1. Am I supposed to fix all the errors and warnings? Will only then my app be published?
2. I found that my app was being tested on different devices different screen size and Rams. Is it possible to specify the minimum screen size and Or RAm in either flutter or the google play console so that my app is only tested on those devices?
3. The one error that caused that crash too is not related to my app also. Shown below

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle
    Process: com.google.android.youtube, PID: 3375
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aewt
        at aewu.b(PG:1)
        at duc.a(PG:230)
        at duc.get(PG:247)
        at aevw.b(PG:1)
        at dud.al(PG:5)
        at dud.aw(PG:4)
        at dud.bg(PG:8)
        at duc.a(PG:232)
        at duc.get(PG:247)
        at afke.a(PG:1)
        at aeri.b(PG:1)
        at dud.fv(PG:4)
        at duc.c(PG:269)
        at duc.get(PG:247)
        at amfk.a(PG:1)
        at eiu.K(PG:5)
        at dud.fV(PG:7)
        at duc.d(PG:334)
        at duc.get(PG:247)
        at com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.common.notification.FcmMessageListenerService.b(PG:1)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.g(PG:53)
        at avgp.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at usj.run(PG:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Answer (score 10):

Answers to your questions:

1. You are not required to fix all the errors and warnings. Having errors and warnings does not block you from publishing. Pre-launch report is used to help you find the most common errors just in case you missed them in testing, but it will not find all errors.
2. You can't change test devices on the Google Play console. However, you could use Firebase Test lab which allows you to select devices which you want to test on.
3. You can ignore that error. Pre-launch report seems to be reporting all errors that happen on the device so you can ignore the ones not related to your app.

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=en-GB

Comment: My app is in review but I have got 2 error and says "Errors found. Fix before releasing to production.". So if I leave it like that will the review be completed eventually?

Comment: As I said above, errors do not block you from publishing and your app will still get published after it has been reviewed

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering the same. The app status remains "In Review" so i guess that is a sign that it has not been rejected even though there are errors.

Comment: "In review" means it is being checked by Google for policy violations. Nothing to do with  pre-launch reports.